# Ajax requests in Wordpress, can't get my custom function to execute

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am making ajax requests in wordpress to `admin-ajax.php` file using jQuery:

```
function ajaxSubmit() {
    var FormData = jQuery(this).serialize();    
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: FormData, 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
$('#form').submit(ajaxSubmit);
```

here is the code from `functions.php` file:

```
function activitysubmitTeamMeetingPt(){
    die(var_dump($_POST, $_GET));
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_activitysubmitTeamMeetingPt', 'activitysubmitTeamMeetingPt' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_activitysubmitTeamMeetingPt', 'activitysubmitTeamMeetingPt' );
```

Also, in the form I do have a hidden attribute for `action`

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submitTeamMeetingPt" />
```

As per the code, all form data would be printed on the screen but that doesn't happen. And I have verifed from firebug that `Xhr` request to `admin-ajax.php` is being fired but for some reason `activitysubmitTeamMeetingPt()` doesn't get called/executed and ajax request just returns 0 with http statuscode 200.

Now,I am wondering was why `activitysubmitTeamMeetingPt()` is not being executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update, I figured it out. hidden attribute for `action` should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="activitysubmitTeamMeetingPt" />
```

now it works just fine. thanks for looking everyone